# mariadb-server installation

Tags: kubuntu, lts

I just installed mariadb-server on Kubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

```
apt install mariadb-server
mysql_secure_installation
```

so far so good, then I tried to login after setting root password

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

then I did

```
service mysql status
```

and I saw

```
61108 18:04:29 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' has both a password and an authentication plugin specified. The password will be ignored.
```

This is where I ended up after trying all sort of attempts (like purge, reinstall, mysql_install_db, etc..) to overcome this. This shouldn't be like that, right? Any solutions?

Comment: `sudo -i`, enter password and then `mysql`. If that works set up your user and password

Answer (score 1):

I found this https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/ article which put light on the question.

Just to recap, after the installation do:

```
mysql -u root -p 
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('s0mePassword'), plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And now I can login the way I am used to.

I still don't understand why this changed in a way that mysql_secure_installation can't handle but anyway, this is how it goes now.